# Cannot connect asp.net web forms to local mySQL db

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have wasted nearly a month trying to resolve this issue and have had no luck.  I think I have tried everything I can find in the forums.
So at the moment all I want to be able to do is have my asp.net web forms connect to my local database and to be able to use the asp.net Identity.

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017 (Version 15.9.3) and have downloaded the latest MySQL Workbench 8.0 (Version 8.0.13) also downloaded the latest MySql.Data.dll (Version 8.0.11.0).

So that I can be sure that it is not something I have done else where in my project I have created a new asp.net web app (.net framework).  I have selected web forms and changed the Authentication to Individual User Accounts.

In web config I have changed the following:

```
<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="server=localhost;User Id=root;password=****;database=testdb" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>

<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Within mysql workbench I have created a new Schema called testdb.

When I run the project I get this error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The Entity Framework provider type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.'

I have followed the link the error gives me but I am not sure exactly what it is telling me, I know some people will tell me it is given me the answer but I have spent so much time reading it I have no idea what it is telling me now.  I am not asking for people to give me the but I really do need some help.

Edit:

Thank you Bradley and SH7 that got the web site started with out an error, now I am not sure if I need to start a new question here, but when I click on Register and enter my email and password it gives me this error.

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.'
MySqlException: Table 'testdb.aspnetusers' doesn't exist
```

Yes I know that means that the table does not exists, but I was under the impression that when you first register a user it would create all the tables needed for Identity.. While I am waiting for help I will add a new table and see if I can connect to that.

Comment: Don't use `MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.8.3.0` with `MySql.Data` 8.0.11; they are not compatible. Install https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFramework instead. Also, the latest version of https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/ is now 8.0.13. If you use the right packages and are still getting an error, please edit your question with the new error message and we'll try to help.

Comment: please make sure if you have enabled the Property `CopyLocal` to `true` for `MySql.Data.dll` in Project Reference.

Comment: Thank you Bradley and SH7, I will try now and will let you know how I get on